# Will GCM Network Manager work on non-Play devices?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, android-jobscheduler

As a replacement to `JobScheduler` for Android prior to 5.0, Google released [GCM Network Manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) that automatically uses native JobScheduler in Android 5.0 and some custom code for older ones.

However, I am not sure if it works on non-Play devices (those without Google Play Services), like Kindle and Blackberry 10 and China phones. From the name it seems that it has something related to GCM, so I suspect it only works on Play devices.

Can anyone confirm about this?

Comment: You have to add a dependency to google play services. I would guess the Network Manager will not run on devices without play services.

Comment: from the docs `It requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the Google Play Store application installed, or or an emulator running Android 2.2 with Google APIs. However, you are not limited to deploying your Android applications through Google Play Store.`

Comment: Too bad. It looks like it has nice features like auto retry/exponential backoff when we say that the task failed, and so on..

Answer (score 5):

Of course it needs google play service 7.5.0+ installed on the device,

> GcmNetworkManager was added in Google Play Services 7.5.0, so it will
>   not work on older versions. (Announcement blog post here:
>   http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/a-closer-look-at-google-play-services-75.html)

Comment: Could you provide any alternative to GCM Network manager which runs without google play services